# Appcode launch fails with "Config and system paths seem to be equal"

Tags: intellij-idea, appcode

I just re-started `AppCode` and there is apparently a configuration problem:

[image]

I went to the `/Applications/AppCode.app/Contents/bin' directory and neither`idea.config.path`or`idea.system.path` exist in any of those files. In fact *none of the files have been modified from their original installation values*.

Is there any way to avoid re-installing? I would likely lose my run configurations and projects info. Also then the root cause would remain a mystery and might re-surface.

**Update** this also happens for `Intellij`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an `idea.properties` under  `~/Library/Preferences/AppCode2019.3` that did have those values. I removed them from that file and `AppCode` now launches correctly.

I suspect this happened in relation to importing settings from an intellij project.